# MVC Model is null in HTTPOST

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

There's a number of questions about this already, but despite looking over quite a few of them I'm having trouble seeing where the problem is here. When I submit the below form, the model is null. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

Model (Partial):

```
public class ItemHeader
{
    public string hdr_contact_name { get; set; }
    public string hdr_contact_method { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        int id2 = (int)id;            
        DB db = new DB();
        ItemHeader itemHeader = db.GetHeader(id2);
        if (itemHeader == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(itemHeader);
        }      
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(ItemHeader itemHeader)
    {
        string test;
        DB db = new DB();
        Response.Write(db.UpdateHeader(itemHeader));
        Response.End();
        return null;
    }
```

View (Partial):

```
@model MVCTest2.Models.ItemHeader
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Vendor Contact</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_contact_name, new { style = "width:24em", maxlength = 40 })</td>
                <td>Email/Phone</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hdr_contact_method, new { style = "width:24em", maxlength = 40 })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>         
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Html (partial):

```
<div>
<form action="/MVCTest2/VendorItem/Details/69" method="post">    
    <h4>Item Request Details</h4>
    <hr />
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>Vendor Contact</td>
          <td><input id="hdr_contact_name" maxlength="40" name="hdr_contact_name" style="width:24em" type="text" value="" /></td>
          <td>Email/Phone</td>
          <td><input id="hdr_contact_method" maxlength="40" name="hdr_contact_method" style="width:24em" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
</form></div>
```

Comment: I edited the post to include fields that aren't disabled (the majority of the fields are not and would not explain why the entire model is null.)

Comment: Can you validate you did not nest multiple forms?

Comment: Can you post the resultant HTML?

Comment: There are no nested forms; I verified by searching the HTML source just in case. Also I've posted the form HTML for the fields being shown here.

Comment: I'm not sure if this information is helpful, but I've got a breakpoint set up in VS in the HttpPost function above; when I look at the value of this/modelstate I can see that any changes I type into the form before hitting submit are captured in those variables even though the itemHeader object is null.

Comment: Can you try adding a parameter to your HttpPost method `int? id` ? Just before the `ItemHeader itemHeader` parameter.

Comment: Nice catch! As soon as you said it I was sure it would work. Tested to confirm and that did the trick. If you can edit your answer I'll mark that as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form is posting to `/MVCTest2/VendorItem/Details/69` but the action method `POST Details` does not have the `id` parameter.

Try using this instead of what you actually have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(int? id, ItemHeader itemHeader)
{
    string test;
    DB db = new DB();
    Response.Write(db.UpdateHeader(itemHeader));
    Response.End();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that disabled fields aren't submitted; it is a partial of the model and view, however, and the majority of the fields are not disabled--I just didn't see the sense in shoving the 30 fields and associated view code into the post. I edited my post to show a couple of the other fields instead.